# Backup data filled in with cs_seo TYPO3 extension

Tags: export, typo3, backup, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I'm using the SEO extension cs_seo for a TYPO3 website. I am looking for a way to export or backup the data filled in with the extension. For example, you can manually set the meta-description among other things for any page. I want all that information for all the pages in one export. Is that possible somehow?

I'm using TYPO3 8.7.27

Answer (score 1):

The extension has the file `ext_tables.sql` where all tables and fields are shown that are created by the extension.
It has the two tables `tx_csseo_domain_model_meta` and `tx_csseo_domain_model_evaluation` and furthermore it extends the table `pages`:

```
CREATE TABLE pages (
  tx_csseo_title_only tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    tx_csseo_keyword varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  tx_csseo_tw_creator varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  tx_csseo_tw_site varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
);
```

TYPO3 has the option to create exports with individual combination of data. If you concentrate on all the data in the tables and fields shown above you can create an export only for the extension.
The resulting export is saved in a file-format specific for TYPO3: t3d (like TYPO3 data).

Another option would be creating in the backend a CSV-file, but I don't know if it's possible to create that for the whole pagetree by the TYPO3-internal export-option for CSV.

Surely it's possible to make a data-backup with a bit sql too as all the tables and fields are known.

**Edit**
The easiest way is to click on the backup option in the extension-manager. There it had to be checked if the data of the table pages are included.

Comment: The backup option of the extension manager would be the best and easiest. However, on my live site, which is 8.7.27 I cannot find that option. Only on the dev site, which is 8.7.4. I think I read somewhere that they wanted to remove that feature?

Comment: Without checking much now about the export function I can only suggest to install the extension impexp (typo3/cms-impexp) and perhaps lowlevel (typo3/cms-lowlevel) to get the functionality back. I'm not sure if that's working though.